# How to disable escaping html chars in wordpress?

Tags: html

I am trying to add some JavaScript code in my WordPress post and it is converting "&&" to "&&#38", breaking the JavaScript code.

How do I disable this escaping ?

Comment: Are you pasting it into the Text Editor or the Visual Editor?

Comment: Doing this will create a major security hole, you shouldn't need to insert JS into a post directly in the DB, have you considered shortcodes?

Comment: Users with the `unfiltered_html` capability can add JavaScript inside posts. By default, this is super admins on multisite and admins on single site. You'll need to use the "Text" editor and not the "Visual" editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write some code, you can use a shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'unescape_js', 'add_js_code' );

function add_js_code( $atts, $contents = '' )
{
    $contents = html_entity_decode( $content );
    return $contents;
}
```

## Usage - in text editor

[unescape_js] Your js code && more js codes...[/unescape_js]

But saving js code directly into DB is not recommended at all.